# Relay to toggle 2 power sources

Tags: relay, powerbanks

I wanted to use some MOSFETs for my power bank/almost UPS but I will do it first with a relay to keep things simple.

Is my relay connected correctly in this (uncompleted) diagram? I guess I can split in 3 the positive voltage like that without problem?

Thank you!

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Need a datasheet for the relay. Normally they have two coil terminals plus C/NC/NO, so I'm not sure what "signal" is. Also, how does the battery negative connect to in- of your USB PD board?

Comment: @Finbarr Thanks! "Signal" was what I saw on a relay module I have, it's where I normally connect my Arduino/ESP32 boards to use the relay, I don't know the accurate English name :|

For the ground of the PD board, maybe I really misunderstand, I think they all share the same ground so their ground is always connected together?

Comment: You don't need a relay module, just a plain relay. A module allows you to control the relay using an MCU with a lower voltage/current drive than the relay coil requires but that's not necessary here.

Comment: As for the grounds, they might or they might not. In- and Out- of the charger might not be connected directly and then you have no ground from battery to PD module.

Comment: @Finbarr "You don't need a relay module, just a plain relay." You are 100% right! Also, less components = less risks of problems. And I will check if the grounds are really connected, else I could use another relay I think 

Comment: Use a double pole relay rather than adding another single.